# Cython cannot find the declared function from cimported module

Tags: cython, cythonize

System: Mac OS 10.12.6. 
Python: Python 3.5.2 from Anoconda3.
Cython==0.28

I am trying to write the wrapper for a static c++ lib. Here is the part of the header file.

```
/* LexActivator.h */
#pragma once
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    #ifdef LEXACTIVATOR_EXPORTS
        #ifdef LEXACTIVATOR__STATIC
            #define LEXACTIVATOR_API extern "C"
        #else
            #define LEXACTIVATOR_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
        #endif
    #else
        #ifdef __cplusplus
            #ifdef LEXACTIVATOR_STATIC
                #define LEXACTIVATOR_API extern "C"
            #else
                #define LEXACTIVATOR_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
            #endif
        #else
            #ifdef LEXACTIVATOR_STATIC
                #define LEXACTIVATOR_API
            #else
                #define LEXACTIVATOR_API __declspec(dllimport)
            #endif
        #endif
    #endif
    #if defined(USE_STDCALL_DLL) && !defined(LEXACTIVATOR_STATIC)
        #define LA_CC __stdcall
    #else
        #define LA_CC __cdecl
    #endif
    typedef const wchar_t* CSTRTYPE;
    typedef wchar_t* STRTYPE;
#else
    #define LA_CC
    typedef int32_t HRESULT;
    #if __GNUC__ >= 4
        #ifdef __cplusplus
            #define LEXACTIVATOR_API extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default")))
        #else
            #define LEXACTIVATOR_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
        #endif
    #else
        #ifdef __cplusplus
            #define LEXACTIVATOR_API extern "C"
        #else
            #define LEXACTIVATOR_API
        #endif
    #endif
    typedef const char* CSTRTYPE;
    typedef char* STRTYPE;
#endif

#define LA_USER ((uint32_t)1)
#define LA_SYSTEM ((uint32_t)2)
#define LA_V_TRIAL ((uint32_t)1)
#define LA_UV_TRIAL ((uint32_t)2)

LEXACTIVATOR_API HRESULT LA_CC SetProductFile(CSTRTYPE filePath);
```

And here is the part of the `pxd` file for Cython.

```
from libc.stdint cimport *
cdef extern from "LexActivator.h":
    ctypedef int32_t HRESULT
    ctypedef const char* CSTRTYPE
    ctypedef char* STRTYPE

    uint32_t LA_USER = 1
    uint32_t LA_SYSTEM = 2

    uint32_t LA_V_TRIAL = 1
    uint32_t LA_UV_TRIAL = 2

    HRESULT SetProductFile(CSTRTYPE filePath)
```

And I write a simple `pyx` file for the test.

```
cimport LexActivator
def SetProductFile(filePath):
    cdef bytes py_bytes = filePath.encode()
    cdef const char* c_string = py_bytes
    cdef int32_t status = LexActivator.SetProductFile(c_string)
    print(status)
    return status
```

Setup file

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
ext_modules=[
    Extension("LexActivator",
              sources=["LexActivator.pyx"],
              language='c++',
              extra_objects=["libLexActivator.a"], 
    )
]
setup(
    name = "LexActivator",
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)
)
```

Run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport LexActivator

def SetProductFile(filePath):
    cdef bytes py_bytes = filePath.encode()
    cdef const char* c_string = py_bytes
    cdef int32_t status = LexActivator.SetProductFile(c_string)
                                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

LexActivator.pyx:7:38: cimported module has no attribute 'SetProductFile'
```

PS: I have successfully done this with Xcode for only c code.

Comment: The root of your problems might be, that pdx and pyx files have the same name. Try naming pdx-file something like CLexActivator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your exact error but I think the issue is that you're overwriting `SetProductFile`.

`pxd` files with the same name as a `pyx` file are automatically cimported -  equivalent to `from LexActivator cimport *`. Thus, you don't need the the `cimport LexActivator`. The problem occurs because the `def` function `SetProductFile` has the same name as your C function (which confuses Cython - I get a warning rather than an error though)

I would also avoid using the same name from your Cython and your C files. Cython compilation generates a `LexActivator.c` file, and in some cases a `LexActivator.h` file, and so it is easy for your own C files to be overwritten if they have the same name.

---

In summary, you have two options:

1. Rename your Python `def` function (and drop the `cimport LexActivator`)
2. (as @ead suggested) Rename your `pxd` to something else, do `cimport SomethingElse` and then your `SetProductFile` won't conflict names.